# Timedelta calculation on Dataframe column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of Dataframe

```
    Datetime            HomeTeam        AwayTeam    HG  AG  FT  
0   2021-06-05 21:30:00 Palestino   U. De Chile                                                                 
1   2021-06-05 17:00:00 Cobresal    Union La Calera                                                                     
2   2021-06-01 02:30:00 A. Italiano U. De Chile                                                         
3   2021-06-01 00:00:00 Union       Nublense                                                                
4   2021-05-31 21:30:00 Antofagasta Huachipato                                                              
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
68  2021-03-28 01:00:00 U. Espanola S. Wanderers    3   1   H                                   
69  2021-03-27 22:30:00 Colo Colo   Union La Calera 0   0   D
```

I want to calculate the datetime different between "Datetime" column and today if "FT" column is blank

Code:

```
today = datetime.today()
if [df['FT'] == ''] == True:
    for date_ in dates_:
        delta = date_ - today
        if delta.days < -1:
            print(date_)

OUTPUT


date_
NaT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly convert your Datetime column into datetime[ns] dtype by using `to_datetime()` method(If it's already in datetime dtype then ignore/skip this step):

```
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
```

You can use boolean masking:

```
mask=df['FT'].isin([float('NaN'),' ',None,'  ',''])
```

Now get today's date:

```
today=pd.Timestamp('now')
today=pd.DateOffset(days=today.day,hours=today.hour,minutes=today.minute,seconds=today.second)
```

Finally pass that mask:

```
df.loc[mask,'FT']=df.loc[mask,'Datetime']-today
```

Comment: I got `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'`

Comment: can you please tell the full traceback?

Comment: I convert it into Datetime column and works. But I have to know which date is passed

Comment: Updated answer...Kindly have a look ***:)***